# Loop for adding/appending 3+ arrays explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I found this on here a few days ago. I am a beginner so I find my self very curious as to how the more complicated stuff works. I am trying to figure out how this works. Anyone care to add some comments or explain how this works? Original question I pulled this from did not provide any explanation. I'm still learning so take it easy. Thanks!

```
function sum(a, b) {
    Object.keys(b).forEach(k => {
        if (b[k] && typeof b[k] === 'object') return sum(a[k] = a[k] || {}, b[k]);
        a[k] = (+a[k] || 0) + +b[k];
    });
    return a;
}

var test1 = { testSystem: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22" }, testSystem1: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22" }, testSystem2: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22" }, testSystem3: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "1", low: "22" } },
    test2 = { testSystem: { crit: "19", high: "305", med: "21", low: "212" }, testSystem1: { crit: "111", high: "10", med: "31", low: "62" }, testSystem2: { crit: "21", high: "3", med: "11", low: "232" }, testSystem4: { crit: "13", high: "40", med: "15", low: "22" }, testSystem7: { crit: "21", high: "3", med: "112", low: "32" } },
    test3 = { testSystem5: { crit: "1", high: "0", med: "122", low: "122" }, testSystem2: { crit: "2", high: "6", med: "1", low: "222" }, testSystem3: { crit: "6", high: "0", med: "12", low: "212" }, testSystem4: { crit: "4", high: "8", med: "11", low: "2" } };

console.log([test1, test2, test3].reduce(sum));
```

Comment: Some docs that might help you: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), [logical operators (including `||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I guess I should say I understand what all of those do on a basic level but things l ike: how does b[k] represent all values crit through low? Why does it not throw error trying to add a[k] to b[k]? Would that  not try to add the strings for testsystemX? The function is using a, b but in the console.log it is passing in 3 objects? Could you add as many as you wanted?

Comment: `[].reduce` calls the passed function with the result of the last call and the next item in the array, so it calls `sum(test1, test2)` then takes that result (let's call it `res`) and calls `sum(res, test3)`, etc. until there are no array items left to call `sum` on, at which point it returns the final result. Here's some pseudocode to help you understand `sum`, which by the way is a recursive function (that's how a[k] and b[k] are added):

Comment: Call the following code with every key in the object `b`, the key having the variable `k`:
If the key `k` in the object `b` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and is an object (e.g. maps key to values, not an integer or string), (this is ridiculously concise syntax and hard to read/explain, but I'll try my best) return the result of calling `sum` (this function) with the arguments the key `k` in the object `a` if it exists or `{}` if it doesn't (also assigns `{}` to `a[k]` if not) and the key `k` in the object `b`.

Comment: If the above code wasn't executed (the function calling itself and returning), the key `k` in the object `a` is set to itself if it exists (no effect) or `0` if it doesn't, plus the key `k` in the object `b`. `a` is then returned. (I highly recommend taking a look at @Jorge Solis' answer, it offers a more general explanation of the key components of the code.)

Answer (score 1):

You should look for some exercises so you hone your logic skills and abstract thinking.
I'll try to provide an answer to your questions:

1: It looks for what's inside the keys of an object, if it's an object, the function calls itself again (and wiil do so until it finds something different than an object)

2: It tries to cast the 'thing' to a number when it does find something different than an object

```
a[k] = (+a[k] || 0) + +b[k];
```

Which is: *if a[k] exists, treat it like a number, or use 0, then add b[k] to it, treating it like a number as well.*

3: testsystemX are not strings, are keys of every testX object, each of them containing several keys at the same time (from crit through low).

4: The function is using a and b because those are the parameters it was defined with. These parameters are provided by the reduce() function. Also, in the log function there aren't three objects, it's logging the result of .reduce() called on the array [test1, test2, test3]. 
reduce() returns an object, an array, or anything you want. In this case it's an object formed from what reduce() returns on each iteration.